# Is there an operator error because after execution it is saying ambiguous error. What error am i doing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
elder_data.head()
    Sex      Name       Fund    Elder Rating    Caretaker Rating
0   Female  A'A NAYHIA  56154           3               3
1   Male    AADHAV      31118           3               4
2   Female  AADHYA      23523           3               2
3   Male    AADIT       13202           2               2
4   Male    AADITH      39505           2               4


 if elder_data['Elder Rating'] >=3 | elder_data['Caretaker Rating'] >=3:
    elder_data["Status"]="Approved"
else:
    elder_data["Status"]="Not Approved"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-646b023be552> in <module>
----> 1 if elder_data['Elder Rating'] >=3 | elder_data['Caretaker Rating'] >=3:
      2     elder_data["Status"]="Approved"
      3 else:
      4     elder_data["Status"]="Not Approved"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1477                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1478                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1479 
   1480     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

** I want to create a new column "status" where if Elder Rating and Caretaker rating is greater than 3 the status would be approved

But I am getting an error. How can it be corrected?**

Answer (score 5):

First problem is missing `()` in chained conditions because operator precedence and for set new values is used [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
elder_data["Status"] = np.where((elder_data['Elder Rating'] >=3) | 
                                (elder_data['Caretaker Rating'] >=3),
                               'Approved',
                               'Not Approved')
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jezrael mentioned in his answer, You are missing `()`.

You can also make use of a boolean mask to index the dataframe and replace the values are necessary using `loc` like this,

```
mask = (elder_data['Elder Rating'] >=3) | (elder_data['Caretaker Rating'] >=3)

elder_data['Status'] = 'Not Approved'
elder_data.loc[mask] = 'Approved'
```